# shell script to get collect pixel size of image

Tags: bash, images

I'm trying to create shell script that returns the largest picture in total dimensions pixel size?

For example:

I have many directory over 7000+, each directory have images:

```
dir_1/
picture_1.png = 800x600
picture_2.png = 80x100
picture_3.png = 80x640
picture_4.png = 500x630

dir_2/
p_1.png = 800x600
p_2.jpeg = 800x1000
p_3.png = 180x1640
p_4.gif = 500x30
```

So the result expected is:

```
 the largest one in dir_1 is: picture_1.png 
 the largest one is dir_2 is: p_2.png
```

So I was thinking is best way is to find out the total of dimensions after collect the figures ..
therefor I try to create bash script with sips command that can collect the figures

Here example :

```
 for f in *;
 do
 far=$( cd $f/OEBPS/image/ | ls * | egrep 'jpg|png|jpeg')

 W=$( sips -g pixelWidth $far | cut -f 2 -d":" )
 H=$( sips -g pixelHeight $far | cut -f 2 -d":" )

 coll=$(expr $W + $H)
 echo $f total is: $coll
 cd -
 done
```

But got error on result.

Any idea or better way?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: For the "largest" image, do you want to consider the perimeter or the area?

Comment: Don't do "cd" in scripts. You can iterate from your current directory over the files too. And don't do "ls" in scripts. In bash, you can do: `for f in  $f/OEBPS/image/*{png,jpeg,jpg}`. A ls will bite you if you have blanks and such in fillenames.

Comment: Also, what if two or more images in the same directory have the same size ?

Comment: I've fix by add identify "$image" 2> /dev/null ...
anyhow thanks for your effort ...
last think ..
i want to the result print with urlencode
for example
file:
tadlil kalamy fmt.png
to be
tadlil%20kalamy%20fmt.png
 I'm use MAC OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way to get the height and width in one step:

```
IFS=x read w h < <(identify "$file" | grep -oP '\d+x\d+(?=\+)')
```

`identify` is part of the ImageMagick package.

Your "$far" is surely not what you want:

```
for dir in */OEBPS/image/; do
    for image in "$dir"/*.{jpg,png,jpeg}; do
        IFS=x read w h < <(identify "$image" | grep -oP '\d+x\d+(?=\+)')
        echo $((w*h)) "$image"
    done | sort -n | tail -1 | {
        read size file
        echo "largest in $dir is $file"
    }
done
```

---

Actually, `identify` can take several files, so a more efficient technique:

```
for dir in */OEBPS/image/; do
    identify "$dir"/*.{jpg,png,jpeg} |
    awk '{split($(NF-6), a, /x/); split($0, b, /[[]/); print a[1]*a[2], b[1]}' |
    sort -n | tail -1 | {
        read size file
        echo "largest in $dir is $file"
    }
done
```

The awk command is a bit complicated because I want to handle image names that may contain spaces

Comment: first script seems is good but need little fix .. i got the result but in same-time i got error like: 
     
     
     /OEBPS/image/*.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2675
     /OEBPS/image/*.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2675

seems the script try to find all dir with jpg,jpeg,png and print it to me
just need to hide that

Comment: add `shopt -s nullglob` before the for loop

Comment: you could also discard identity's stderr: `identity "..." 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=""
max=0
for f in /OEBPS/image/*{png,jpg,jpeg}
do
  id=$(identify "$f") 
  size=$(echo ${id} | sed -r 's/.* (JPEG|PNG) ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+) .*/\2*\3/')   
  area=$(($size))
  if (( area >= max ))
  then
    max=$area
    file="$f"
  fi
done
echo $max $file
```

- Don't use *ls* for iterating over files in scripts - blanks in filenames will brake them.
- Don't *cd* around.
- We don't need sorting to find the biggest file by area.
- For doing arithmetic in bash, you don't need *expr*, but $((a*b)).

Identify needs *ImageMagick*.

The *sed*-command will fail if your filename looks too close like the output of *identify*.